# How do you set the WrapperElement name for returned collections in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a web service that has methods similar to:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getCampusList")
@GET
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public List<Campus> getCampusList() {

  List<Campus> campuses = campusService_.getCampusList();

  if(campuses.isEmpty()) {
     throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
   }

   return campuses;
}
```

Campus is JAXB annotated and works great, but the encapsulating root element is collection.  Is there a way to change that to campuses?  Are there any reasons that that would be a bad idea?  Below is a snippet of the current return value.

```
<collection>
  <campus>
    <address>
      <street1>3000 Ivyside Park</street1>
      <city>Altoona</city>
      <state>PA</state>
      <postalCode>16601-3760</postalCode>
    </address>
       <code>AA</code>
       <id>2</id>
       <latitude>40.541118</latitude>
       <longitude>-78.411003</longitude>
       <mapUrl>http://maps.google.com/maps?z=16&q=40.541118,-78.411003</mapUrl>
       <name>Altoona</name>
  </campus>
  <campus>
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour will vary among JAX-RS implementations as they are the ones providing the root element when a collection is returned. You could return a wrapper object that contained a property of type `List<Campus>` that was annotated with `@XmlRootElement(name="campuses")`.

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Campuses {

    @XmlElement(name="campus")
    private List<Campus> campuses;

}
```

Then you would create separate get methods for XML and JSON to have the appropriate return types.

**XML**

```java
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public Campuses getCampusListXML() {

  List<Campus> campuses = campusService_.getCampusList();

  if(campuses.isEmpty()) {
     throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
   }

   Campuses response = new Campuses();
   response.setCampuses(campuses);
   return response;
}
```

**JSON**

```java
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Campus> getCampusListJSON() {

  List<Campus> campuses = campusService_.getCampusList();

  if(campuses.isEmpty()) {
     throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
   }

   return campuses;
}
```

Comment: That's along the path I'd started.  Thanks for the feedback.